# How to change issuer Name while creating X509Certificate2 in C#

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, x509certificate2

I am working with creating X509Certificate2 certificate in my C#.net application. While creating certificate, how to set the issuer name? currently issuer name shows same as subject name.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.

Finally I have used **Bouncy Castle dll** to create certificates.Using this, there is a method to set issuer name.

This is the fully code to generate **x509Certificate** and to store into **Trusted People** store:

```
 private X509Certificate2 GeneratePFXFile(string certificate,string company,string   email,string state,string locality,string username,string country)
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert = null;
        try
        {
            var kpgen = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();

            kpgen.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(new CryptoApiRandomGenerator()), 2048));

            var kp = kpgen.GenerateKeyPair();

            var gen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

            var certName = new X509Name("CN=" + certificate);
            var issuer = new X509Name("C="+country+",O="+company+",OU=LBC Mundial Corp.USA,E="+email+",L="+locality+",ST="+state);
            var serialNo = BigInteger.ProbablePrime(120, new Random());

            gen.SetSerialNumber(serialNo);
            gen.SetSubjectDN(certName);
            gen.SetIssuerDN(issuer);
            gen.SetNotAfter(DateTime.Now.AddYears(50));
            gen.SetNotBefore(DateTime.Now);
            gen.SetSignatureAlgorithm("MD5WithRSA");
            gen.SetPublicKey(kp.Public);

            gen.AddExtension(
                X509Extensions.AuthorityKeyIdentifier.Id,
                false,
                new AuthorityKeyIdentifier(
                    SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(kp.Public),
                    new GeneralNames(new GeneralName(certName)),
                    serialNo));

            gen.AddExtension(
                X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage.Id,
                false,
                new ExtendedKeyUsage(new ArrayList() { new DerObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") }));

            var newCert = gen.Generate(kp.Private);
            byte[] pfx = DotNetUtilities.ToX509Certificate(newCert).Export(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType.Pfx, (string)null);

            X509Store store = new X509Store((StoreName)StoreName.TrustedPeople, (StoreLocation)StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

            cert = new X509Certificate2(pfx,(string)null, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

            store.Add(cert);
            store.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowError(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
        return cert;
    }
```